# Django ValidationError: ["“('1',)” value must be either True, False, or None."]

Tags: python, django

why i am having getting this error ?  **["“('1',)” value must be either True, False, or None."]** did i miss something in my code? i am trying to update the data and i receive this error.

This is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Ubo"  value="1" {% if feedback.q5Ubo %}checked="check"   {% endif %}>
<input type="checkbox" name="Lagnat"  value="1" {% if feedback.q5Lagnat  %}checked="check"  {% endif %}>
<input type="checkbox" name="Sipon"  value="1" {% if feedback.q5Sipon  %}checked="check"  {% endif %} >
<input type="checkbox" name="Lbm"  value="1" {% if feedback.q5LBM  %}checked="check"  {% endif %}>
```

This is my views.py

```
Ubo = request.POST.get('Ubo') or 0
Lagnat = request.POST.get('Lagnat') or 0
Sipon = request.POST.get('Sipon') or 0
Lbm = request.POST.get('Lbm') or 0
```

this is my models.py

```
q5Ubo = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
q5Lagnat = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
q5Sipon = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
q5LBM = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

**UPDATE** i change my html and views.py

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Ubo"  value=True>
<input type="checkbox" name="Lagnat"  value=True >
<input type="checkbox" name="Sipon"  value=True >
<input type="checkbox" name="Lbm"  value=True >
```

views.py

```
Ubo = bool(request.POST.get('Ubo')) or False
Lagnat = bool(request.POST.get('Lagnat')) or False
Sipon = bool(request.POST.get('Sipon')) or False
Lbm = bool(request.POST.get('Lbm')) or False
```

this is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/TracingSettings/TracingApp/views.py", line 865, in Data
    insert_2tab.save()
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 872, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 803, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1522, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1143, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1488, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 818, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 967, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/MyHealth/contacttracingapp/ctenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 957, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(

Exception Type: ValidationError at /Data/
Exception Value: ['“(False,)” value must be either True, False, or None.']
```

this is my full views.py

```
    q1 = request.POST.get('q1')
    q2 = request.POST.get('q2')
    q2Reason = request.POST.get('q2Reason')
    q3 = request.POST.get('q3')
    q4 = request.POST.get('q4')
    q4Reason = request.POST.get('q4AnswerDetailed')
    q5 = request.POST.get('q5')
    q6visitedPlacesDuringNonWorkingDays = request.POST.get('q6visitedPlacesDuringNonWorkingDays')
    Ubo = bool(request.POST.get('Ubo')) or False
    Lagnat = bool(request.POST.get('Lagnat')) or False
    Sipon = bool(request.POST.get('Sipon')) or False
    Lbm = bool(request.POST.get('Lbm')) or False
    paghinga = bool(request.POST.get('paghinga')) or False
    Pananakit = bool(request.POST.get('Pananakit')) or False
    katawan = bool(request.POST.get('katawan')) or False
    Pagkawala = bool(request.POST.get('Pagkawala')) or False

insert_2tab = TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords(
        dateSubmitted=datenow,
        fmCustomerID=company,
        fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID=fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID,
        q1Answer=q1,
        q2Answer=q2,
        q2AnswerDetailed=q2Reason,
        q3Answer=q3,
        q4Answer=q4,
        q4AnswerDetailed=q4Reason,
        q5Answer=q5,
        q5Ubo=Ubo,
        q5Lagnat=Lagnat,
        q5Sipon=Sipon,
        q5LBM=Lbm,
        q5HirapSaPaghinga=paghinga,
        q5PananakitngUlo=Pananakit,
        q5PananakitngKatawan=katawan,
        q5PagkawalaNgPangAmoyatPanlasa=Pagkawala
        
    )
    insert_2tab.save()
```

Comment: Please use Django's model forms instead of writing forms by hand.

Comment: Please show us the whole traceback and the function where the error is happening.

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen i posted now my fulltraceback

Comment: You somehow get a tuple value instead of single value, Do you use serializers to handle model creation? Can we see the full code of your view?

Comment: @AKX, can you answer his question by writing a django form and applying the solution to it.
some of the new Django programmers don't really know forms exist.
your answer should be a good reference for the new programmers having the same problem in the future (writing forms by hand).

Comment: @marvin your question can be answered by typing 
Ubo = bool(eval(request.POST.get('Ubo'))[0]) or False
instead of 
Ubo = bool(request.POST.get('Ubo')) or False
and so on ..
**BUT DON'T APPLY IT**
the whole concept  of writing forms by hand isn't a good idea for most cases.
you should read about [Django forms][ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/] which will put you on the right track

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your *"hand written form"* isn't working, and I suspect most other users don't either, because **you shouldn't write forms by hand**!

It will be much easier for **both of us**, if I show you how to use a form with your setup.

In a file traditionally called **`forms.py`**, create a new form class for your model:

```
from django import forms
from .models import TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords as ThisNameIsTooLong


class ThisNameIsTooLongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ThisNameIsTooLong
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, in your **`views.py`**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
form django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, SuspiciousOperation

from .forms import ThisNameIsTooLongForm

def my_view(request):
    form = ThisNameIsTooLongForm(request.POST or None)
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # handle valid form here. eg:
            return redirect('some_view')
        else:
            # handle invalid form
            raise ValidationError('form was invalid')
    
    # method was neither "GET" nor "POST", raise a 405: Method Not Allowed
    raise SuspiciousOperation(405)
```

Finally, in **`my_template.html`**, you will need to render the form via the form object passed into the template context:

```
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_ul }}
<button>save</button>
</form>
```

I'm not sure where your **`feedback`** object is coming from, so I left out the programmatic toggling of the form input's value.  If you want the same functionality that your current setup has, you will need to find a way to pass the **`feedback`** to the form's **`__init__`**, for example:

```
feedback = {'q5Ubo': True}
form = ThisNameIsTooLongForm(request.POST or None, feedback=feedback)
```

And in your form class:

```
class ThisNameIsTooLongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ThisNameIsTooLong
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, feedback=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if feedback is not None:
            for key, value in feedback.items():
                self.initial[key] = value
```

You should really give the **[`form docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/)** a read if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

You have created the field as Boolean. So it should return either `True` or `False`. Also, it will accept `None`, because you have added null = True.

But the value you are currently getting from HTML is a string. You have to convert it into boolean.

```
Ubo = bool(request.POST.get('Ubo'))
```

Updates:
As per @ElrondSupportsMonica, `or False` is not needed. `.get(key, default=None, /)` will return the key, if the key is there, else it will return the default value.  For the default value, we have `None`. `bool(None)` will be False. So or False is not needed.

Comment: Hi @Navaneetha Krishnan ive tried to change my code with your answer, and i receive the same error, i post my updated question, please check

Comment: I tried with your html and view.py. Working for me. Don't know which line you are getting this error

Comment: can you print this `insert_2tab` before insert_2tab.save() and see the output.

Comment: You don't actually need to `or False` at the end. the `.get` method returns `None` if the key isn't found, and `bool(None) is False`

Comment: @ElrondSupportsMonica. Yes. You are right..!. I will change the answer.